# JSONP with Angularjs doesn't work with TwitchTV api

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, jsonp

I've been trying to build a little app with Angular and the [TwitchTV api](https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API) but I'm having a lot of trouble with JSONP.  It seems like I can pull in the data just fine, but crawling through Object nets me a white screen of nothing.  I get no errors either so debugging has been impossible.  Here is my current set up.

**SERVICE**

```
  .factory('twitchTEST', function($resource){
    var resource = $resource('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/nl_kripp/videos',{},{
      query:{
        method:'JSONP',
        params: {callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'},
        isArray:false,
        headers:{
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          'Accept': 'application/vnd.twitchtv.v2+json',
          'Client-ID': 'fcn1buiw3t57k9yduoqvwxdk3awb2rf'
        }
      },
    });
    return resource;
  });
```

**CONTROLER**

```
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, twitchTEST) {
    twitchTEST.query(function(data){
      $scope.twitches = data;
    });
  });
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="twitch in twitches">
  <span>{{ twitch.name }}</span>
</div>
```

With this set up I get just a white screen.  The odd part is that if I change the template to just :

```
<div ng-repeat="twitch in twitches">
  <span>{{ twitch}}</span>
</div>
```

I then will get the entire object.  For some reason I dont know how to just get a name, status, or any other field.  I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong at this point.  A bit lost.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a moron. I just realized there is nothing in the OBJECT to repeat on... So sorry for the time wasting guys.  Maybe this will help someone else out there who is up way to late for their own good.